# Laravel Join and groupBy Cannot Show Column Data

Tags: php, laravel

```
$result = DB::table('students')
        ->join('cities', 'cities.id', '=', 'students.city_id' )
        ->select('cities.city_name as CityStudent', DB::raw('COUNT(students.id) as total'))
        ->groupBy('cities.id')->get();

view blade :

@foreach($result as $r)
<tr>
       <td>{{ $r->CityStudent }}</td>
       <td>{{ $r->total }}</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

I want to display the number of cities. And display the name of the city in the data.
Why does the code error and it doesn't work?

Comment: try this      join('students', 'cities.id', '=', 'students.city_id' )

Comment: Firstly, what error are you getting? Secondly, do you have models set up for these tables? If so, do you also have a `students` relationship set up on the `City` model?